# enter is making page break in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

In Microsoft Office 2016 Word I have some heading 2s separated by the Enter key.

In between these heading 2s, I press another Enter, and it produces a page break.

Additionally, if I change a block of text to the "Normal" style, this produces a page break after that block of text.

This behavior has never occurred before.

I've performed a Quick Repair and the issue remains.

I've performed an Online Repair and the issue remains.

I've started a new document, pasted the content in, and the issue remains.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Post a small example document.